# Prevent Checkstyle files creation in maven projects target folder

Tags: java, intellij-idea, cucumber, checkstyle, rest-assured

With the help of Idea Intellij IDE I am creating one Maven Project In which I am using checkstyle.
I have kept checkstyle files in src/config folder after successful compilation and run of project one target folder get generated in which this checkstyle files got automatically generated.
I don't want this files to be generate in the target folder.
Please let me know if any one have workaround on that.

[image: You can check here the screenshot of the checkstyle files getting generated]

Comment: Do you mean that checkstyle reports are generated in target folder?

Comment: Yes I dont want that to be created in target folder. I have tried to use  
 <resource>
    <directory>src/config</directory>
    <excludes>
        <exclude>src/config/*.xml</exclude>
        <exclude>src/config/*.txt</exclude>
    </excludes>
</resource>
But its of no use for me.